# meteor exception: The package named router does not exist

Tags: node.js, meteor, meteorite

I am trying to create new meteor + meteor-router project.
I installed meteor and meteorite and then:

```
$ meteor create myapp
$ cd myapp
$ mrt add router
$ meteor
```

Whet I get is the following exception:

```
[[[[[ ~/dev/naorye/fbsignature/V1/linkit ]]]]]

No dependency info in bundle. Filesystem monitoring disabled.
=> Errors prevented startup:
Exception while bundling application:
Error: The package named router does not exist.
    at _.extend.initFromPackageDir (/Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/tools/packages.js:155:13)
    at _.extend.initFromWarehouse (/Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/tools/packages.js:197:10)
    at Object._.extend.get (/Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/tools/packages.js:347:15)
    at self.api.use (/Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/tools/bundler.js:111:28)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Object.self.api.use (/Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/tools/bundler.js:110:9)
    at _.extend.init_from_app_dir [as on_use_handler] (/Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/tools/packages.js:238:11)
    at _.extend.use (/Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/tools/bundler.js:450:11)
    at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/tools/bundler.js:859:12)
    at /Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/tools/run.js:694:26
    at exports.inFiber (/Users/naorye/.meteor/tools/275efdf2db/tools/fiber-helpers.js:24:12)

Please fix the problem and restart.
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to start your app with `mrt` as opposed to `meteor` (Meteorite uses `mrt` as a shell for everything meteor can do, except that it incorporates the packages into your app)

Update: In the newer version's of Meteorite this need not apply anymore. Packages added with `mrt add xxx` should 'just work' with `meteor`.

Comment: So I just need to type 'mrt' instead of 'meteor'?

Comment: yes thats it. `meteor` doesn't know how to find packages installed with `mrt add xxx`